# How to install the appointments module with composer?

Tags: 8, composer

I am trying to install the [appointments](https://www.drupal.org/project/appointments) module, but running `composer require drupal/appointments` fails because some 3rd party libraries are not installed. I am using the [drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) composer template.

The [module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/appointments) refers to some composer commands for installing these libraries but I am unsure whether these should be run from the command line or whether they should be included within the composer.json file (and if so where?).

How to install the appointments module with composer?

Comment: Literally follow the instructions on the module page and it'll work. Running `composer config` will update your composer.json where necessary. The installer paths section should be added manually by you

Comment: Thanks for this Clive. I was misunderstanding the part about manually adding the installer paths. If you'd like to post your answer I'll be very happy to accept it.